# java code control program not compiling. class A, class B, class C,

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, extends

```
class A implements Once {
    
    public void one () {
        System.out.println("A.1") ;}
    
    public void two () {
        one();
        System.out.println("A.2") ;}
    public void sayItOnce () {
        System.out.println("i'll say it once") ;}
    }

 class B extends A implements Once, Twice {
        
        public void one (int x) {
            System.out.println("B.1" + x) ;}
        
        public void two () {
            System.out.println("B.2") ;}
        
        public void sayItTwice () {
            System.out.println("\"i'll say it Twice") ;}
    }
 
 class C extends A {

        public void one() {
            System.out.println("C.1") ;}
    }
 
 interface Once {
        public void sayItOnce ();

    }
 interface Twice {
        public void sayItTwice ();
    }
`
```

This is an exam question from a previous year if the following piece of code were to appear in a control program that used the classes A, B and C what would be the outputs? (i) (ii) - (vi)

```
class control{

        //(i)
        A a1 = new B ();
        a1.two();
        
        //(ii)
        B b1 = new B();
        b1.one(4);
        b1.one();
        
        //(iii)
        Once r = new B();
        r.sayItOnce();
        
        //(iv)
        Twice b2 = new Twice();
        b2.sayItTwice();
        
        //(v)
        C c1 = new A();
        c1.two()
        
        //(vi)
        A a2 = new B();
        a2.sayItTwice();
        
        //(vii)
        A a3 = new C();
        a3.two();}
```

so that's the code we were given I wanted to know if the code is wrong or is there something I'm missing?
I get these errors

> "Identifier expected"  a1.two();
>
> "Delete this token" b1.one(4);
>
> "Identifier expected"  b1.one();
>
> "Identifier expected" r1.sayItOnce();
>
> "Identifier expected" b2.sayItTwice();
>
> "Type mismatch cannot convert from A to C" C c1 = new A();
>
> "Identifier expected" c.two();
>
> "Identifier expected" a2.sayItTwice();
>
> "Identifier expected" a3.two();

that's all the error obviously the main error is "Identifier expected" I'm not sure how to fix that.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this is really code you were given and the question was "what is the output" the answer is obviously that there is no output as the class control is not valid java code. Method calls are not valid in that place in a class. It is missing the main method to run any code at all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compile any Java code that isn't within a method. Wrap these statements like this:

```
class Control{
  void x(){
    //(i)
    A a1 = new B ();
    a1.two();
    //...

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Control class, code is written as such without any method or code block. First,put the code in either main method or some method to compile this program.

Regarding this error, "Type mismatch cannot convert from A to C" C c1 = new A(); ---> we cannot put object of parent class into child class reference directly.